# Use array index to change background color to element

Tags: arrays, dom, background-color

I have created an ul element and I have put some li items inside. I want to change the background color of each li item using an array in a for loop. This is what I have, but the result is just a string :(

```
"use strict";

var colorArray,
    i,
    ulVar,
    listItem;

colorArray = [
      "color1", 
      "color2", 
      "color3", 
      "color4", 
      "color5", 
      "color6"
 ]

 ulVar = document.createElement("ul");
 ulVar.setAttribute("id", "#text-color");
 ulVar.innerText = "Some unordered list"
 document.body.appendChild(ulVar);

 for(i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++){
     listItem = document.createElement("li");
     listItem.setAttribute("class", colorArray[i]);
     console.log(listItem.getAttribute("class")); //just to check what's inside
     listItem.innerText = colorArray[i];
     ulVar.appendChild(listItem);
 }
```

The css code is just this:

```
#text-color {
color: #fff;
}

.color-1 {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}

.color-2 {
    background-color: #ff6600;
}

.color-3 {
    background-color: #cc00cc;
}

.color-4 {
    background-color: #009933;
}

.color-5 {
    background-color: #669999;
}

.color-6 {
    background-color: #663300;
}
```

I don't know how to make the colorArray[i] to return the class properties and not just string. I'm learning now so please don't judge me too hard :)

Comment: You use color1, color2,.. first, but in your css you use color-1, color-2,.. Remove the - in the names in your css file and try again.

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!! I'm so stupid! I have been watching this code for the last 4 hours!!! Did everything and nothing happened and  I haven't seen that!!! :@ Thank you and srry for the question at all :)

Comment: @Dennisvdh Ahhh I didn't see your comment before I answered. Apologies.

Comment: @Dennisvdh the moment you answered I saw that  :@ Thank you one more time and srry again for the stupid mistake!

Comment: Could you mark my comment as useful and the answer too?